# Fast Range naming in Excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel, range

I'm working on a C# project where Excel files are extensively used. Most of the values in the sheets' cells are referred by assigning a name to a Range which identifies a single Cell.
Until now all sheets were assembled iterating through single cells: each one was inserted singularly along its name and format, and obviously it was painfully slow.
Trying to speed things up, I managed to insert arrays of data into one sheet, but Istill haven't found how to do the same thing with Range Names.
I'm still stuck whith this code

```
for (var row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
{
    for (var column = 1; column <= columns; column++)
    {
        string refCell = GetExcelColumnName(column) + row.ToString();
        myExcelWorkbook.Names.Add(labels[row - 1, column - 1], sheet.Range[refCell , refCell ], true, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    }
}
```

which is even slower than the previous version (it takes MINUTES to fill a list of ~10000 names). So I was wondering if there is a way to make this insertion in a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to make your range names cover multiple cells so that there are many fewer named ranges.